# Check if two lists are equal up to a permutation

Tags: r

In R, how can one check if two lists are equal, up to a permutation?

For example,

```r
l1 <- list(diag(3), diag(c(-1,-1,1)))
l2 <- list(diag(c(-1,-1,1)), diag(3))
```

I would like `l1` and `l2` to be considered equal.

At present, what I have is

```
library(purrr)
map_lgl(l1, function(x) any(map_lgl(l2, function(y) identical(x,y))))
```

It works for this example, but it is not very elegant.

What could be a better way to achieve this?

Comment: A *base* way might be: `all(sapply(l1, function(x) any(sapply(l2, function(y) identical(x,y)))))`

Answer (score 3):

can there be such an option?

```
l1 <- list(diag(3), diag(c(-1,-1,1)))
l2 <- list(diag(c(-1,-1,1)), diag(3))
dplyr::setequal(l1, l2)
```

Comment: This will work also with `base::setequal(l1, l2)` or simple `setequal(l1, l2)`

Comment: Great! this works. I think you don't need the `dplyr::` though, as `dplyr` imports `base::setequal()` anyway. In any case, thanks for pointing me to `setequal()`!

Comment: @Gki yup, although from the docs, it seems that `dplyr::setequal()` refers to `base::setequal()`

Comment: Both force matrices to vectors.

Comment: It will say that `list(diag(c(-1,-1,1)), c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1))` is identical with the given lists `l1` and `l2`. Is this OK?

Comment: apparently, yes. `identical(as.vector(diag(3)), c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1))`

Comment: Is there a difference between `matrix(0, 2, 3)` and `matrix(0, 3, 2)`? I would say yes. Only if you convert them to a vector this difference will disappear.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But `setequal` works the way it works.

Comment: @GKi That's a good point. I would _not_ wish for `list(matrix(0,2,3))` and `list(matrix(0,3,2))` to be considered equal. Sorry Yuriy Saraykin, I shall unaccept this answer, as I did not consider the matrix dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Though it has been marked as answered by an elegant answer, but still if you want to understand the working of `purrr` you may write

```
all(map_lgl(l1, \(x) any(map_lgl(l2, ~ all(x == .x)))))

[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same like in the question but using *base* functions:

```
all(sapply(l1, function(x) any(sapply(l2, function(y) identical(x,y)))))
#[1] TRUE
```

Packed in a function and testing with other list:

```
L1 <- list(diag(3), matrix(0, 2, 3))
L2 <- list(matrix(0, 2, 3), diag(3))
L3 <- list(diag(3), matrix(0, 3, 2))

f <- function(a, b) {
  all(sapply(a, function(x) any(sapply(b, function(y) identical(x, y)))))
}

f(L1, L2)
#[1] TRUE
f(L1, L3)
#[1] FALSE
f(L2, L3)
#[1] FALSE
```

In case names should not be considered, use in addition `unname`.

```
f <- function(a, b) {
  all(sapply(a, function(x) any(sapply(b, function(y)
    identical(unname(x), unname(y))))))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User Yuriy Saraykin suggested to use `setequal()`. It works for most cases, but does not consider the `dim`ensions of the matrix. Nevertheless, it led me to a solution:

Inspecting the code for `setequal()`, we see that it checks for `match(x,y)` and `match(y,x)`. The function `match()` returns us the corresponding indices for which `x` is equal to `y`, and vice versa. Thus, if there are no NA values, then `x` is a *subset* of `y`, and vice versa. This makes sense, as two sets are equal iff they are subsets of each other.

However, a quick test shows that `list(matrix(0, 2, 3))` `match`es `list(matrix(0, 3, 2))`, though these are clearly not identical. Thus `match()` does not respect matrix dimensions. To my understanding, this is why -- as a few users pointed out -- `setequal()` does not respect matrix dimensions.

But `match()` gives us a *possible* permutation `p` so that `l1[p]` *could* be equal to `l2`. Although matrix dimensions are not respected, this can be checked with `identical()`. Thus we can use

```r
identical(l1[match(l1,l2)], l2)
```

Comment: Try it with `l1 <- list(matrix(0, 2, 3), matrix(0, 3, 2))` and `l2 <- list(matrix(0, 3, 2), matrix(0, 2, 3))`.

Comment: @GKi that's a good (failed) test case. Thanks